# How do you get evince to display svgs?

Tags: svg, evince

Evince does not support svgs on its own, however I have the following situation:

1. Ubuntu 11.04 / Evince 2.32.0
2. Ubuntu 11.10 / Evince 3.2.1
3. Debian 7.0 / Evince 3.4.0

Now, the odd thing is, on *1.* I can open svg files with plain `evince` and it renders them correctly. On both *2.* and *3.*, however, I cannot as Evince tells me

> #### Unable to open document
>
> File type SVG image (image/svg+xml) is not supported

So, I suspect system *1.* (which is the only one not under my control) has some sort of plugin to display svgs. But I don't know if Evince even has a plugin feature, let alone how to list the plugins --- all I know is that it is possible.

**So, how do I get my (newer) version(s) of Evince to understand svg files?**

---

I am ***not*** asking for suggestions for other viewers; I know and use them (but they have their drawbacks).

Comment: Evince uses `poppler` for displaying PDF and postscript. It might be possible, that an older version supported SVG as well. Maybe you can help us with adding the output when using evince on a command-line, i.e. `evince xyz.svg`. Especially the output of the working setup (1) would be interesting.

Comment: @MartinBetz: The working Evince (1) doesn't print anything regarding the svg, except saying several times "`** (evince:19211): WARNING **: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/lib/vgfs/gvfsd-metadata: Success`" which seems to be some dbus error with a module that is *not* loaded. So it shouldn't influence its attitude towards svgs.

Comment: Ok, that really does not help. I would contact Evince's developers directly. There is plenty of ways to do so, including a mailing-list and an IRC channel. Let us know if you find out something!